# Invalid Index Column, llamado de procedimiento desde Java (Oracle)

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedure, oracle-11g

Estoy intentando llamar un procedimiento de Oracle desde Java, el problema es que me da el Invalid Index Column exception y no se a que se debe.

[image: CODIGO DE JAVA][image: PROCEDIMIENTO EN ORACLE]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

Si esa es una SQLException lanzada por Java, lo más probable es que esté intentando obtener o establecer un valor desde un ResultSet, pero el índice que está usando no está dentro del rango.

Por ejemplo, podría estar intentando obtener la columna en el índice 3 del conjunto de resultados, pero solo tiene dos columnas que se devuelven de la consulta SQL.
saludos